# Installing MS09-056 (KB974571) on Live Communications Server

Tags: patch-management, ms-office-communicator

I've just installed this patch on a Live Communications Server 2005 server and LCS is refusing to start.

I'm getting a wonderful event log claiming that the LCS instance is an expired evaluation (!)

Looks like there's an incompatibility between this patch and LCS.

OCS people might want to check for their version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, Richard, JFGI!

There are loads of postings, e.g. [Microsoft's Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/974571/en-us) that say that there is an incompatibility and don't do it!

Apparently, uninstalling the patch fixes LCS / OCS.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this was a bit unfortunate. A patch that stops every OCS server on the planet from starting up certainly got the dev team's attention very quickly :-)

Comment: Upvoted just for the honesty - Microsoft are so much more open these days